# Update array while editing cell while running the App

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, uitableview

I've got a `tableView` in the ViewController & an array called `toDo`, in the TableView I've a cell and in the cell I got textView.
the textView is editable (The user can change the text in the textView).
After the user changes the text - I want the cell to save it to the toDo array, but whenever I reloaddata the text disappears.
Here is what I tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.textField.text = toDo[indexPath.row]
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
```

**I have a got a test button that whenever I click it reload data.

Comment: Please show the code where you are updating the toDo with the modified text.

Comment: The code is in the question: `cell.textField.text = toDo[indexPath.row]`.
Unless I'm not coding the right thing..

Comment: This shows how you read the information from toDo, but the important part is how do you *write* the information to toDo when the user updates the text. Does it make sense?

Comment: @MirekE I guess I didn't write it.. Can you give me an example of how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out - set the tag on the text field and implement `textFieldDidEndEditing:` to update your model before reloading the table view.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.textField.text = toDo[indexPath.row]
    cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.textField.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    toDo[textField.tag] = textField.text
}
```

Comment: It worked when i changed `textField` to `textView`.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that, whenever the system needs to re-render the cell, the method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` is called; that happens before your text view has a chance to save its content in the data model.  In your case every time you press the button.  I assume you save the content of the text field using optional `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` delegate method.  You can add a `println("SAVING")` in such method, and a `println("RE-RENDERING CELL")` in the tableView(...) method and see the what the sequence of events is.  Nots sure if this could help, but I would try that.

Comment: What would be in the "Saving" method?

Comment: Ok so you probably don't save.  Look at the new answer by Abhianav: clever use of tags, it should work.  I suggested putting println("SAVING") in textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) delegate method to see whether it is called and when.